# Managed to uninstall package for keyboard and mouse input. (libinput?)

Tags: package-management, keyboard, mouse

### The keyboard and mouse problem

I am running a laptop with touchpad and keyboard integrated, and I have previously had an issue where my touchpad would make my mouse go in a grid-like pattern. Upon investigating solutions to this issue, I managed to do something incredibly stupid. I removed a package that supposedly controlled my input, and now I can't log in or do anything but hold the power button down when I log into normal mode. Recovery mode works well, but Re-installing packages in recovery seem to not reflect in normal mode.

On the laptop (Lenovo Yoga 710) I have Deepin linux 15.5 installed.
All I know and I can recall I did before I chose to restart it, was that i was uninstalling a package starting at: `xorg-xserver-input-*`but can't really specify the exact package I removed.

As I stated above, I think that my recovery mode doesn't reflect package changes on normal mode (i could be wrong), as I can't get my mouse or keyboard working at all when I then re-log into normal mode. I have tried reinstalling `xorg-xserver-input-all` and even tried with wildcards. Am I missing some configuration?

It's critical for me to get it working until monday, and I guess I am the reason why I made it this way. Has anyone a clue where I could start to get my mouse and keyboard working again? I tried external devices over USB ad bluetooth but none of the input devices are recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got a second machine on the network you can SSH from?

If so, you can ssh in, and manually install libinput as per this documentation:

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building_libinput.html

If ssh is not an option, then I would suggest booting a recovery CD/USB, mount your deepin main partition and compile libinput there as per the documentation above.

Comment: Oh ssh - that's a hilariously good suggestion. I'll give it a shot. I didn't realise it was was an option before now.

Comment: Hello again - Didn't work through SSH, but managed to CHROOT the correct partition (/mnt/sda5) in recovery, and then reinstall the packages needed.That solved my problem. Thanks for your input, it was clever.

Comment: great, glad you got it working @denNorske :)